# Memcached installing issues

Tags: memcached, yum

I am trying to install memcached to REDHAT Enterprise 5.5 x86_64

I have tried:

```
root@sv [~]# yum -y install memcached
```

then recieved below error

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libevent-1.1a.so.1()(64bit) for package: memcached
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libevent-11a.x86_64 0:3.2.1-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: memcached
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(YAML) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(YAML) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Does this mean I need Term::ReadKey, AnyEvent::Socket, AnyEvent etc. in order to install memcached? When I tried to install "AnyEvent" this also gave me some issues.

```
root@sv [~]# rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        perl(EV) >= 3.05 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(Guard) >= 1.02 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(JSON) >= 2.09 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(JSON::XS) >= 2.2 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
        perl(Net::SSLeay) >= 1.33 is needed by perl-AnyEvent-5.240-1.el5.rf.noarch
```

***UPDATE!!!! 01-19-2011***

User: Stephan Kristyn suggested updating some perl modules but that didn't work out for me.
After I updated both modules I ran yum again and here is the result.

```
root@sv [~]# yum -y install memcached
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
rpmforge                                                            | 1.1 kB     00:00     
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: libevent-1.1a.so.1()(64bit) for package: memcached
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-libevent-11a.x86_64 0:3.2.1-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML) for package: memcached
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: memcached
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(YAML) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Socket) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(AnyEvent::Handle) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(YAML) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, on CentOS 5.5 x86_64, I had success with the following:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=rpmforge,rpmforge-extras install memcached
```

Obviously you need [RPMForge](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge/Using) for this to work. (Since the yum log mentions rpmforge, @Maca seems to have it already.)

The problem was that the required version of perl-Net-SSLeay was included in the **rpmforge-extras** repository, which was disabled by default.

While not the same package was problematic as in the question, the same reason and solution may apply.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me at first and then I realized there's an update to RPMforge. So update RPMforge first and then do this. It should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS’s yum repository doesn’t have the latest perl-Net-SSLeay and perl-IO-Socket-SSL packages that are required by memcached. I did some Googling to find that others were experiencing a similar problem without resolution. Here’s the simple fix:

First, remove the old perl modules. Then download and install the newer versions that memcached requires.

```
rpm-e perl-Net-SSLeay-1.30-4.fc6
rpm -e perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.01-1.fc6
wget http://packages.sw.be/perl-Net-SSLeay/perl-Net-SSLeay-1.36-1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm
wget http://packages.sw.be/perl-Net-SSLeay/perl-Net-SSLeay-1.36-1.el5.rfx.x86_64.rpm
wget http://packages.sw.be/perl-IO-Socket-SSL/perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.34-1.el5.rfx.noarch.rpm
rpm -i perl-Net-SSLeay-1.36-1.el5.rfx.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i perl-Net-SSLeay-1.36-1.el5.rfx.i386.rpm
rpm -i perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.34-1.el5.rfx.noarch.rpm
```

Now you should be able to install memcached without error.

yum -y install memcached

Credits and more info: http://mattdanger.net/2010/12/perl-net-ssleay-dependency-error-when-installing-memcached-with-yum/

Comment: thanks for looking that up. I will try this later and report.

Comment: Hey I tried it out. It didn't work out for me. Both Net::SSLeay is v1.36 and IO::Socket::SSL v1.37 which is recent version.

Comment: Also I added the results after the description part.

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualization tool or control panel has certain packages disabled in the yum configuration; consult the developer of said tool as for how to fix this.

Comment: I have cPanel installed. Maybe thats why

Comment: Yes, cPanel is one of the known offenders.

Comment: What would be the consequences of using `--disableexcludes` with yum for this in a cPanel environment? I've just installed memcached using this switch with no problems yet...

Comment: @battal: You *could* potentially damage the other tool this way; only the tool's provider can say for certain.